# How do I make a JButton clickable only once without adding count on subsequent clicks?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have a grid of `JButton` controls, and clicking a button will show a number. The first 7 buttons clicked will be Yellow, and the 8th button will be Green. I do that by using 'Count'. However, I'm currently facing a problem whereby I click the same button and it still increases the count and by the 8th click the button will turn from Yellow to Green.

I've attached my action listener method below:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalButton; i++)
    {
        if (event.getSource() == jbArray[i])
        {
            jbArray[i].setText (String.format("%d", alist.get(i)));

            if (count == 8)
            {
                jbArray[i].setBackground (Color.GREEN);
            }
            else if (count < 8)
            {
                jbArray[i].setBackground (Color.YELLOW);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also a `removeActionListener` method for `JButton` (actually for `AbstractButton`)

Comment: *"How do I make a JButton clickable only once"* When it is clicked, call `button.setEnabled(false);` this is a better solution than proposed by @MichaelButscher - whose approach will not provide the user with hints, the user might keep activating one button repeatedly, not understanding why it has 'broken'. BTW - if that does not solve the problem, post a [mcve] to give us a better idea of how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an array of buttons. You will need some way of keeping track of which jButton was clicked. You could create another array called clicked[], and store which button was clicked. Then, you could iterate through the array to see if the clicked number matches the current button. If it is not on your second list, run your color change code, and then add it to the array of clicked[].
   That is just one example, there are other ways of course, bu the idea is to track what has been clicked and only execute the color changer when it shows the button has not been clicked.